# print text when calling a model

Tags: r, printing, summary

I hope this is not a double post. I've been looking for an answer.

I have a function that returns a rather big list. So i would like it to print some text in between all the results of the list. A bit as you know it from lm and other models.

Consider this R script

```
y<-function(z)
{
l<-list()
print("hello world")
l$answer<-2*z
return(l)
}
x<-y(5)
```

This is a small example. I tried a solution with print but this is a bad solution , simply because it executes print when i save the variable as x<-fun(5). I just want it to execute text when you ask it explicit, or even better,if you can construct your own "summary" command to a list.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: the answer below was what occurred to me first, but another way would be to add a `print = FALSE` argument to `y`, add `if (print)` above the print statement, and only set to TRUE when you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you want to do , I think you are looking to implement the S3method `print`.

1. set the class attribute :"someclass" of the y function return value
2. define `print.someclass`

here the code:

```
y<-function(z)
{
  l<-list()
  l$answer<-2*z
  ## Roland comment : usually better to preserve existing classes:
  class(l) <- c('someclass', class(l))
  return(l)
}

print.someclass<- 
  function(x,...){ ## add here what you want to print 
                print("hello world")
 }

x<-y(5)
```

Now when you type x at console or print(x):

```
x
[1] "hello world"
```

Comment: I know you are aware of this, but I'd like to point out that it's usually better to preserve existing classes: `class(l) <- c('someclass', class(l))`

Comment: @Roland yes of course. thanks.fixed. ( next time please feel free to edit my answer if you want of course)